How to run test cases in typescript using native rust?
How can I run test cases in typescript using native rust not anchor.

You can use mocha and chai or jest Javascript test frame works same as with anchor. You would just not use the anchor provider.
You can also use https://kevinheavey.github.io/solana-bankrun/ then you dont even need to start a local validator.
Here is a simple counter example with tests
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/basics/counter/native/tests/counter.test.ts
You can just run the tests with yarn test

Any idea like how can I increase timestamp in solana  test cases in anchor and native rust?

Yes you can use bankrun: https://kevinheavey.github.io/solana-bankrun/tutorial/#time-travel Here is a working example: https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-preset/blob/main/program/jesttests/energy-refill-time.test.ts You can also use npx create-solana-game  to create a project with these tests setup already.
